# npm install brings errors - gyp verb

Tags: npm, cmd

I use npm all the time and it works smoothly until I tried to run it today in a folder (that has a package json with dependencies) and after 10 seconds the cmd brought me the following errors:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\USER\Documents\OPCloudProject\OPCloud-client\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\USER\Documents\OPCloudProject\OPCloud-client\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\USER\\Documents\\OPCloudProject\\OPCloud-client\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your version of node is not supported by that projects version of node-sass.

You can check what architectures node-sass supports here

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

Here is an example of what architectures are supported for node-sass 7.0.1